# How do i make this bit of AJAX code send data to mysql database table?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

**AJAX code**

```js
   $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/javascript/script.php",
            data: {
                "name": the_name,
                "email": the_email
            },
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data)
                var delay = 8000;
                setTimeout(function() {
```

**PHP Code** i have tried so many ways but it doesn't deliever even with console bug i dont find issues

```html
< ?php
   include_once('javascript/db.php');
  
  $email = $_POST['name'];
  $password = $_POST['email'];
  
  if(mysql_query("INSERT INTO `user`(`id`, `name`, `email`) VALUES ('$name', '$email')"))
    echo "Successfully Inserted";
  else
    echo "Insertion Failed";
?>
```

Comment: Stop using the `mysql_*` functions. They have been deprecated since v5.5 (Jun 2013) and removed since v7.0 (Dec 2015). Instead use the [**mysqli_***](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) functions with [**prepared statements**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php) and [**bound parameters**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: @u_mulder could that be the reason? because i removed one field and still didn't work..

Comment: No, definitely. Mysql finds third value somewhere else, no reason to worry.

Comment: @SterlingArcher i dont mind the SQL injection attacks i just want it to send first before i reedit them

Comment: @AlexHowanskyi dont mind the SQL injection attacks i just want it to send first before i reedit them

Comment: Are you certain that you invoke the AJAX function from jQuery, do you have a log statement in front of the AJAX function invocation?

You can log whatever you want in the AJAX callback, if the AJAX function doesn't even get invoked (in case of a misspelled event name or something) than the log obviously won't be printed out in the console.

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network for starters to see what status is

Comment: You're setting the variables `$email` and `$password`, then inserting the varables `$name` and `$email`.

Comment: William the issue here is this question isn't supposed to just help you, it's supposed to help those who visit it. So even though security isn't in mind for you, it makes no sense for us to teach bad, deprecated practices.

Comment: your ajax code is incomplete and we don't know from where  `the_name,the_email` variable come from?

Comment: Is your id column set to auto increment?  Your set-up matters for us being able to answer the question.

Comment: It was actually indicated in the comments that query `INSERT INTO user(id, name, email) VALUES ('$name', '$email')` is incorrect. If you only ever want the values for `name` and `email`, you shouldn't be specifying `id` in the columns list. Not only is this code vulnerable to [SQL Injection Attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/2298301), you also run the risk of it failing totally if deployed with PHP 7. Besides, please check `NETWORK` tab in the console when dealing with AJAX and / or you could run the PHP script directly from address bar to verify if there are any errors in it.

Comment: @Vbudo yes its auto increment.